# Adding values from TinyDB

Tags: app-inventor

So I have a TinyDB with time as a tag and data from Bluetooth as a value,
I want to find a way to sum all the values and store as a variable.

A possible way to do that is create a empty list and sum each item in that list, but how do I create a list with only values from TinyDB and without tags in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will add up all the values in a database.

It uses a for each item block with the get tags block.

Inside that loop, it adds the value of the tag to the sum.

[image: Code screenshot]